# Moq setup for all methods in a class

Tags: c#, moq

This is probably an one-off case. I wonder if it is possible to mock all the methods of a particular type/class with one `setup` if they have the same type and same number of input parameters and the same return type.

My case:

Let's say I have

```
public static IServiceCollection AddMediatR<TDbContext>(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        MyType myType)
{
    services
      .AddMyFirstService(myType)
      .AddMySecondService(myType)
      ...
      .AddMyNthService(myType);

    return services;
}
```

```
public static IServiceCollection AddMyFirstService(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        MyType myType)
{
    var someDeps = myType.GetDepsForFirstService();
    ...
    return services;
}
```

```
public static IServiceCollection AddMyNthService(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        MyType myType)
{
    var someDeps = myType.GetDepsForNthService();
    ...
    return services;
}
```

```
public class MyType : IMyType
{
  public IReadOnlyList<Type> AddMyFirstService()
  {
     // return a list of some type as read-only
     // or 
     return new List<Type>().AsReadOnly();
  }

  public IReadOnlyList<Type> GetDepsForNthService()
  {
     // return a list of some type as read-only
     // or 
     return new List<Type>().AsReadOnly();
  }
}
```

For the above case, if I mock MyType, is there any better way other than creating mock setup for each of my `GetDeps` method considering they take the same number and type of input parameters and return the same type i.e. `IReadOnlyList<Type>` in this case?

Comment: I don't know a trick here but you should reconsider if that would be a good idea. Test should be explicit. Magic in setup tends to be working even when it should fail and you might miss problems. For example when the class under test changes and the count of those equal looking methods changes shouldn't your test fail. It might coincidentally but i don't see a  guarantee here with the magic applied you wish for.

Comment: I'm unaware of a solution which is available out of the box, but with Reflection and some hand made `Expression` it is viable.

Comment: I want to note that while Mocking frameworks are great for some use cases, there are cases where it is just simpler to create your own actual mock class. If you have a large amount of methods that only differ by name, you might consider creating a single method with a enum parameter, and extension methods for convenience. See for example many logging frameworks where you have a method that takes a LogLevel, and extension methods you avoid needing to specify this each time.

Comment: Many thanks for insightful comments. Suggestion from JonasH and Ralf made me rethink my whole approach.

Comment: This is a code smell. They are called "Unit tests" for a reason. Does it seem to you like you are testing a "unit"? The moment you find yourself in situations like these, you should take a step back and re-evaluate what you are doing.

Comment: Understood that now. Many thanks!